# PostgreSQL, unable to update row ( with row level security )

Tags: postgresql

```
set role qstoolbox;
update contract set contract_reference = 'ok ok ok' where id = 2
```

The above works
Query returned successfully: one row affected, 41 msec execution time.

```
set role user_role;
update contract set contract_reference = ':( :( :(' where id = 2
```

This one doesn't
Query returned successfully: 0 rows affected, 31 msec execution time.

[image]

Permissions seem ok, at least its not clear what I'm doing wrong here.

Row level security has been added to this table with

`alter table contract enable row level security;`

Along with these policies

```
create policy view_contract on contract for select using(true);
create policy add_contract on contract for insert to user_role with check(true);
create policy delete_contract on contract for delete to user_role using(true);
create policy change_contract on contract for update to user_role with check(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I was missing something in this line

`create policy change_contract on contract for update to user_role with check(true);`

Needs to be

`create policy change_contract on contract for update to user_role using(true) with check(true);`

Note I was missing **using(true)**

Thanks to @klin for making me study the docs in more detail

Answer (score 2):

Define a row security policy or disable row security on the table. Per [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html):

> When row security is enabled on a table (with ALTER TABLE ... ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY), all normal access to the table for selecting rows or modifying rows must be allowed by a row security policy. (However, the table's owner is typically not subject to row security policies.) If no policy exists for the table, a default-deny policy is used, meaning that no rows are visible or can be modified.

Comment: I think I'm doing this already, have updated question, also I think this is what is being displayed in the pgadmin screen shot?

Comment: Yes, you were mising `using()`. The picture do not show security policies.