# Row Level Security Enabled update is not working while standard update does using the same logic

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, policy, row-level-security

Working on postgres 10.4 (on RDS if it makes a difference) I am trying to enforce application user permissions using Row Level Security.

I have a permissions table which looks something like

```
user_group_id | entity1 | entity2 | entity3 | permission
==============|=========|=========|=========|============
1             |1        |null     |null     | write
1             |1        |1        |null     | read
```

1. entity1(root)-entity2-entity3(leaf) is a hierarchy of items stored in different tables. entity1 contains entity2 items, entity2 items contains entity3 items.
2. permission are inherited meaning entity3 inherits the permissions from entity2, entity2 inherits the permissions from entity1, unless:
3. Rows with matching entity3 override rows with matching entity2 which override rows with matching entity1.

In the above example user group 1 has write on all entity2/entity3 under entity1=1 (1st row) except for entity2=1 and all entity3 under entity2=1 on which it has read (2nd row) etc.

I already wrote the logic (i think it's not relevant to the actual question hence not pasting it) as a single query using `dense_rank - which is a window function`.

When I use this logic with an UPDATE directly - it works flawlessly.

When I embed the same exact logic as the `WITH CHECK` of a row level security policy - update refuses to update the rows (I enabled ROW LEVEL SECURITY on the relevant tables - so that's not it).

I tried to embed my logic in a function instead of directly in the policy - but got the same result, meaning this works:

```
--not as table owner
update entity1
set col1=1
where entity1_id=10
and check_access(entity1_id); --updates 1 row
```

but this doesn't:

```
--as table owner
alter table entity1 enable row level security;

CREATE POLICY entity1_update
ON entity1 
AS permissive
FOR UPDATE
TO some_role
WITH CHECK ( check_access(entity1_id) );

--not as table owner
update entity1
set col1=1
where entity1_id=10; --updates no rows
```

Reading the documentation:
`The conditional expression cannot contain any aggregate or window functions` - is that the reason? If so - I would have expected an error to be thrown when trying to create the policy or when actually running the update - but nothing happens.

I also tried re-writing my access check logic using a subquery with ORDER BY and wrapping it with a LIMIT - did not help.

Am I missing something? Any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem - I have another `FOR SELECT` policy on the same table and I assumed its `USING` clause would be sufficient (there's an AND between policies of different `FOR` types) - so I did not include a `USING` clause in the `FOR UPDATE` policy. Once I added a `USING (true)` on the `FOR UPDATE` policy things started working normally (for now at least - I need to do more experiments).

Seems like it has no relation to using a window function.

1. I assume postgres allowed me to create a `FOR UPDATE` policy without a `USING` clause since it allows multiple policies of the same type - but maybe the documentation should have a note that when having a single `FOR UPDATE` policy it **MUST** include both clauses?
   **UPDATE:** I'm not the only one who's update failed for the same reason - 
   [PostgreSQL, unable to update row ( with row level security )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39864202/postgresql-unable-to-update-row-with-row-level-security)
2. This leads me to ask what does the `The conditional expression cannot contain any aggregate or window functions` restriction mean - if it seems to work with using `dense_rank() over (order by...)`... raised [Aggregate/Window functions restriction in Postgres Row Level Security Policy conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54167292/aggregate-window-functions-restriction-in-postgres-row-level-security-policy-con)

Comment: Hey I've read a little from the other question and I believe you must be missing something as AFAIK, a UPDATE policy does not need both `USING` and `WITH CHECK` clauses. But I did not understand your requirements to the extent that I can solve it for you. Maybe if you can post what your table look like without the RLS and describe what should be done from that ... ?

Comment: From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createpolicy.html table 240 states _UPDATE_ evaluates _Existing row_ with _USING_ of _UPDATE_ policy.
Please check yourself and try to contradict my findings - regardless of the use of dense_rank etc.     p.s see the update in #1 of my answer - a similar question got the same answer.

Comment: Basically, you can update every row that matches the `using` clause of at least 1 permissive update policy + all the restrictive update policies (if any). What I'm not getting is why you needed to use a dense_rank from another table within the policy ... All you need is the suitable select policy in the other table and the `USING (<field> IN (SELECT <field> FROM <otherTable>))`, right?

Comment: Or you could define a policy applied for `ALL` so that every row you can select, you can also update them.

Comment: 1. My problem is that I had a WITH CHECK but not a USING in my FOR UPDATE policy. I hope this clarifies why UPDATE did not work.
2. I have a permissions table with different permissions (read/write), inheritance and overrides - see the requirements above. Hence I believe what you suggest cannot work (too simplified) - i.e to modify an entity2=1 under entity1=1, a write permission on entity1=1 is enough, but if I also have read on entity2=1 I cannot modify it.