# Aggregate/Window functions restriction in Postgres Row Level Security Policy conditions

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, row-level-security

I've been successfully able to use a `dense_rank() over (order by...)` 
which AFAIK is a *window function* - in postgres' row level security policy conditions.

However, the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createpolicy.html) states

> Any SQL conditional expression (returning boolean). **The conditional expression cannot contain any aggregate or window functions**

(emphasis is mine).

Can someone explain this restriction and give an example where it applies?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it tells you that each row is independent in regard of row-level security.

Consider the table below:

```
+---------------------+----------------+
| field1              | field2         |
+---------------------+----------------+
| value1              | 1              |
| value1              | 2              |
| value1              | 3              |
| value2              | 4              |
+---------------------+----------------+
```

There are several (permissive) policies:

1. `field1 = 'value1'`
2. `field1 = 'value2'`
3. SUM(field2)> 10 (forbidden but let us imagine for now that you could define it)

You were granted policies #2 and 3 so you can see and update the last record only.
... Until you execute `UPDATE table SET value2 = 11`.

This is really bad in terms of:

- **Security**. You can "grant yourself" access to records, as a user (not as an admin).
- **Maintenance**. Records would keep appearing/disappearing randomly in such database.
- **Performance**. Such policy would have a very big cost to evaluate.

Interstingly, you can define policies as `MyField IN (SELECT MyOtherField FROM MyOtherTable)`, in which case it all relies on what you defined on `MyOtherTable` (it is intended to be used with FK/PK).

Comment: It makes perfect sense. My use of dense_rank is within an _EXISTS_ - so I assume it is a valid use. Thanks!

Comment: You mean in an `EXISTS` that is in a regular query?

Comment: `CREATE POLICY
ON MyTable
...
USING (
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM (SELECT ... dense_rank() OVER (...) computed_rk
                        FROM MyOtherTable) k
                  WHERE computed_rk=1
...`

Comment: Interesting ... That's a complicated one.